# cloned item when clicked to , gets back to original form but doesn't get removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cloned a row of elements. After cloned, the original textbox element is replaced with link. Then if users choose to remove the cloned item, it gets back to original place in original form which is tetxbox. This reversing works fine. Just that the removal of cloned item is not taking place.

WHen clicked on remove, the cloned item is removed but not in entirety.The clicked link's value appended to the next of cloned item in the list.Why does the link didn't get remove?

Below ignore the subject name and focus on the link which carries values starts with RM
Before remove clicked(cloned item)

[image]

After remove clicked(cloned item)
[image]

This is how I clone:

```
function getText(param)
{
  var clony = $("div.clone_this#"+param).remove().clone(true, true).insertBefore("#sub");
  var price = $("input[type=text].text_"+param).val();
 // alert(price);
  clony.find('input[type=text]').replaceWith("<a href='ch'><span class='green' style='font-style:italic;'>RM "+price+"</span></a>");
   clony.find('.cr').append("<a href='del' onclick=removeThis('"+param+"')><img src='/register/cross.png'></a>");

}
```

This is how I remove and change back to original form of element.

```
function removeThis(param)
{
     event.preventDefault(); 


     $("div.clone_this#"+param).detach().appendTo("#sub");
     var price = $("a[href=ch]").text();
     $("div.clone_this#"+param).find($("a[href=ch]").text(price)).replaceWith("<input type='text' onfocusout='getText("+param+")' class='text_"+param+"' val='"+price+"' placeholder='RM'>");

     $("div.clone_this#"+param).find("a[href=del]").remove();
     return false;
}
```

HTML (wrapper only) content injected by jquery

```
    <h2>Finally, choose your Course:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" class="choosen_subjects">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" id="sub">

<!--original list goes here-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle or the HTML code?

Comment: @IrvinDominin, I updated my post with HTML, however content is appended by jQuery

Comment: @IrvinDominin, for your info, if I used only $("div.clone_this#"+param).detach().appendTo("#sub"); No such problem. Only if I used the lines of code below it that it gets appended with prev link's value

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer by myself. The usage of $(this) is solved my problem.

```
function removeThis(param)
{
     event.preventDefault(); 

     $("div.clone_this#"+param).detach().appendTo("#sub");
     var price = $("a[href=ch]").text();
     $(this).find($("#sub a[href=ch]").text(price)).replaceWith("<input type='text' onfocusout='getText("+param+")' class='text_"+param+"' val='"+price+"' placeholder='RM'>");
    $("div.clone_this#"+param).find("a[href=del]").remove();
     return false;
}
```