# managing several show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some scripts here that show and hide divs when click. Now what I need is to just only display one div at a time. I have a code that controls them all but its not working I don't know about much of javascript.

This is the first example of show/hide function that can be done simultaneously without hiding the other `divs`.

FIDDLE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eqs6dy6f/2/)

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')">
Click to show/hide.
</a>

<div id="uniquename" style="display:none;">
<p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>



<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename1')">
Click to show/hide.
</a>

<div id="uniquename1" style="display:none;">
<p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function HideContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}

function ShowContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}

function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    if (document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    }
}

function HideAllShowOne(d) {
// Between the quotation marks, list the id values of each div.

var IDvaluesOfEachDiv = "idone idtwo uniquename1 uniquename";

//-------------------------------------------------------------
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/[,\s"']/g," ");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/^\s*/,"");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/\s*$/,"");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/  +/g," ");
var IDlist = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i<IDlist.length; i++) { HideContent(IDlist[i]); }
ShowContent(d);
}
```

The other fiddle I created would do what I need but the script seems not to be working. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eqs6dy6f/1/)

---

Found the solution on my code thanks to @Abhas Tandon

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eqs6dy6f/5/) the extra id's inside the `IDvaluesOfEachDiv` seems to be making some error with the codes.

Comment: what is the browser support you are looking for

Comment: Sorry, what's all the `HideAllShowOne` supposed to do?

Comment: Looks like you have some extra id's in the `IDvaluesOfEachDiv` Check http://jsfiddle.net/eqs6dy6f/3/

Comment: i think thats the one that will show one section then hides the current open   div. but its not working I'll attached the reference page for the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with IE10+ support then

```js
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle.active:not(#' + d + ')');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(d).classList.toggle('active')

}
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
.toggle.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')">
    Click to show/hide.
</a>
<div id="uniquename" class="toggle">
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename1')">
    Click to show/hide.
</a>
<div id="uniquename1" class="toggle">
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: does the code I use doesn't support on some browser?

Comment: how old browsers do you want to support?

Comment: @MichaelPon in that case it is good enough, see http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I have a posted a question, are you able to answer? You're a reliable expert that I know of, that's why:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166591/cloned-item-when-clicked-to-gets-back-to-original-form-but-doesnt-get-removed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jQuery which is far easier.

Include thiswithin

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

HTML

```
<div id="id_one">Item 1</div>
<div id="content_one">
    content goes here
</div>

<div id="id_two">Item 1</div>
<div id="content_two">
    content goes here
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#content_one").hide();
    $("#content_two").hide();
});

$("#id_one").on("click",function()
{
    $("#content_one").slideDown("fast");
});

$("#id_two").on("click",function()
{
    $("#content_two").slideDown("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *"Button"* for every *DIV* inside your HTML - you can go by element **index**

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
var div = document.querySelectorAll(".ele");

function toggleDivs() {
  for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
    var us = i===[].slice.call(btn).indexOf(this);
    btn[i].tog = us ? this.tog^=1 : 0;
    div[i].style.display = ["none","block"][us?[this.tog]:0];
  }
}

for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++) btn[i].addEventListener("click", toggleDivs);
```

```css
.btn{/* Anchors Buttons */ display:block; cursor:pointer; color:#00f;}
.ele{/* Hidden Divs */     display:none;}
```

```html
<a class="btn"> 1Click to show/hide.</a>
<div class="ele"><p>1Content goes here.</p></div>
<hr>
<a class="btn">2Click to show/hide.</a>
<div class="ele"><p>2Content goes here.</p></div>
<hr>
```